# Why this simple jparsec lexer fails?

Tags: java, parsing, tokenize, lexer, jparsec

I would write a simple lexer that recognises words *without digits* and numbers ignoring whitespaces.

I written the following code using jparsec v3.0:

```java
final Parser<String> words = Patterns.isChar(CharPredicates.IS_ALPHA).many1().toScanner("word").source();
final Parser<String> nums = Patterns.isChar(CharPredicates.IS_DIGIT).many1().toScanner("num").source();
final Parser<Tokens.Fragment> tokenizer = Parsers.or(
        words.map(it -> Tokens.fragment(it, "WORD")),
        nums.map(it -> Tokens.fragment(it, "NUM")));
final Parser<List<Token>> lexer = tokenizer.lexer(Scanners.WHITESPACES);
```

But the following test fails with the exception `org.jparsec.error.ParserException: line 1, column 7: EOF expected, 1 encountered`. Instead, using the string "abc cd 123" the parsing is successful.

```java
final List<Token> got = lexer.parse("abc cd123");
final List<Token> expected = Arrays.asList(
        new Token(0, 3, Tokens.fragment("abc", "WORD")),
        new Token(4, 2, Tokens.fragment("cd", "WORD")),
        new Token(6, 3, Tokens.fragment("123", "NUM")));
assertEquals(expected, got);
```

In your opinion what is wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't the equivalent to your token list be `"abc cd 123"`, since you're lexing based on whitespace?

Comment: According to the documentation, `Parser.lexer(...)` should run the parser (`tokenizer`) repeatedly ignoring the pattern recognized by the delimeter (`WHITESPACES`) before and after each occurrence. It's not clear if the delimiter is optional, so I would expect that the resulting lexer matches "abc", then ignores the whitespace, then matches "cd" and finally matches "123".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved simply by making the delimiter optional:

```java
tokenizer.lexer(Scanners.WHITESPACES.optional(null))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following test pass:

```
public class SOTest {
  final Parser<String> words = Patterns.isChar(CharPredicates.IS_ALPHA).many1().toScanner("word").source();
  final Parser<String> nums = Patterns.isChar(CharPredicates.IS_DIGIT).many1().toScanner("num").source();
  final Parser<Tokens.Fragment> tokenizer = Parsers.or(
    words.map(it -> Tokens.fragment(it, "WORD")),
    nums.map(it -> Tokens.fragment(it, "NUM")));
  final Parser<List<Token>> lexer = tokenizer.lexer(Scanners.WHITESPACES);


  @Test public void test(){
    final List<Token> got = lexer.parse("abc cd 123");
    Asserts.assertArrayEquals(got.toArray(new Token[0]),
      new Token(0, 3, Tokens.fragment("abc", "WORD")),
      new Token(4, 2, Tokens.fragment("cd", "WORD")),
      new Token(7, 3, Tokens.fragment("123", "NUM")));
  }      
}
```

Your tokens are either only `ALPHA` characters or only `DIGITS`, hence it is normal you can't parse `abc cd123`.

The fact that documentation says "delimiters are ignored before or after each occurence" should be interpreted in the sense that delimiters appearing before or after the *list of `Token`s* parsed are ignored. But delimiters are not ignored to separate tokens, except in the case of operators (see `Terminals` class) for more info).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So I've misunderstood the `Parser.lexer` method and it shouldn't used in this way. But finally, how to implement a lexer that accepts "abc cd123" and "abc cd 123" producing the same sequence of tokens (except the offsets obviously)?